# How do I iterate over two lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have troubles in using for loops in Python. I wrote this code:

```
x=5
people=['Mary','Joe']
genders=['she','he']

for person in people:
    print(person)
    for gender in genders:
        if x > 0:
            print("{} is happy".format(gender))
```

and the output is:

```
Mary
she is happy
he is happy
Joe
she is happy
he is happy
```

But I would like the output to be:

```
Mary
she is happy
Joe
he is happy
```

Is there a way to make the for loop iterate over first "Mary" and "she" and then "Joe" and "he" ?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use zip, per below, or [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/). Also, what you're calling 'gender' is not actually a gender; it's a (personal) pronoun.

Comment: it's a toy code... thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why, you can go with `zip()`. Here is a cleaner solution.

```
people=['Mary','Joe']
genders=['she','he']
for person,gender in zip(people,genders):
    print(person)
    print("{} is happy".format(gender))
```

Output:

```
Mary
she is happy
Joe
he is happy
```

Comment: @Manuela. Most welcome. Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it solves the issue

Comment: I have upvoted but I can accept the answer only in 7 minutes (it tells me so) @Sujay

Comment: @Manuela, no problem

Comment: Manuela had meaningful names and you changed it to `i` and `j`. Why, oh why? Please change it back to `person` and `gender`.